# Ruby Name Routes with permalinks and static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several static pages and a couple of dynamic pages.  Static pages are under the "Info" controller.  Dynamic pages are under "products".  I want to access "products" from their :permalink   I can only get map.info or map.products to work but not both.

```
 ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :products
  map.resources :info
  map.root :controller => "products"
  map.info ':action', :controller => "info"
  map.products ':permalink', :controller => 'products', :action => 'show'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you go to http://yoursite.com/something

How can the routes determine if it's a product or info page? It can't, and that's why it won't work. You have to put one of them under a namespace of some sort.

```
map.info ':action', :controller => "info"
map.products '/products/:permalink', :controller => 'products', :action => 'show'
```

Comment: OK, close.  Is it possible to have map.info '/info/:action' and then map.products ':permalink'?  when I try this I get "No action responded to show. Actions:"